# appcfg.py doesn't work- opens source code in sublime

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to update (deploy) a simple hello world python app to the google app engine.  I have created the account through GAE, and the hello world program works via the local host.  when I type

```
appcfg.py update [path-to-helloworld-folder]
```

it just opens up the source code in sublime text.
If I try to deploy the program via the GAE launcher, it directs me to sign in in chrome, but then it just displays the "hello world" on the webpage without actually updating anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're presumably on Windows; you need to type `python appcfg.py ...`.

Comment: ok this actually tried to update the GAE.  but now I am getting Error 403: "You do not have permission to modify this app"

Comment: Well what app are you trying to update? Have you put the name of your own app into app.yaml?

Comment: I am trying to update a simple helloworld app that I have in the GAE.   in app.yaml I have "helloworld" as the application

Comment: Got it to work.  Apaprently I needed to have the unique Project ID as the application in the yaml file...  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as python programs were set to automatically open on my system in sublime.
The problem was resolved by changing python programs to open with python.exe

On Windows:
Right click -> properties

Opens With  -> python.exe